# Why is there a difference of two orders of magnitude in the GHG intensity of "Production of electricity by solar thermal" in Exiobase "ixi" and "pxp"?

Tags: python, io, economics, consumption

When analysing the **M** matrix in Exiobase v.3.8.2 for GHG emissions with 2019 as reference year, I realized there is a difference of one orders of magnitude between the "product by product" and the industry by industry" matrices, for the sector of Production of electricity by solar thermal in Spain. Is anyone aware of this ? Which could be the cause for such a difference ?

This is the code used with the pymrio package, where like='Electricity' when working with the pxp matrix:

```
exio3_2019.impacts.M.loc['GHG emissions AR5 (GWP100) | GWP100 (IPCC, 2010)']['ES'].filter(like='Production of electricity', axis=0)/1e06
```

This gives 30.122842 kg CO2 eq/€ for the matrix "industry by industry" and 3.027458 kg CO2 eq/€ for the matrix "product by product".

Thank you very much for yours insights !
Gonzalo

Comment: I don't know this dataset, so this is a pure guess based on how electricity markets work. Could there be an inconsistency in the units of the underlying price? Electricity in Europe is usually quoted in €/MWh, but in Spain it's sometimes cents/kWh. 1 cent/kWh = 10 €/MWh, so mixing those units would explain a factor-of-10 difference.

Comment: (30.12 vs 3.027 is one order of magnitude, not two orders, right?)